# Jekyll: How can I define my own method?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am using Jekyll (https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll). I don't like to have to write so much just to highlight using Pygment. Currently I have this:

```
{% highlight bash %}    

$ bash <<( curl https://rvm.io/releases/rvm-install-head)

{% endhighlight bash %}
```

I want to be able to do:

```
highlight :bash do

    $ bash <<( curl https://rvm.io/releases/rvm-install-head)

end
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is less about Jekyll, and more about the [Liquid Templating Engine](https://github.com/tobi/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers), which Jekyll uses.

If you really want that feature, the best option is likely to fork Liquid and make the modifications there.

Note, though, that Liquid/Jekyll doesn't just interpret Ruby code.  You'll likely have to dig pretty deep into the lexical analysis/parsing to get your example to work correctly without breaking a lot of other things.

Comment: Damn it, my list of 'things I'd like fork' has increase again :) Vote up for the nice info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so fond of the liquid templating syntax either. But this textmate snippit (mapped to the tab trigger 'code') makes it a bit less painful.

```
{% highlight ${1:bash} %}
$2
{% endhighlight %}
```

Hopefully you can something similar to your text editor of choice.